Significance indicators are not appearing on a graph in R
I am relatively new to R and having issues with displaying the asterisks for significant differences, even though the ANOVA and Tukey posthoc show p <0.05. I also cannot seem to get the tukey comparisons to only show comparisons to Concentration_0. Any help would be appreciated
Code:
# Step 0: Packages

library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)

# Step 1: Create the data frame (Your provided data)
data <- data.frame(
    Concentration_100 = c(37064, 43632, 41114, 30876),
    Concentration_10  = c(45548, 47482, 41894, 44574),
    Concentration_1   = c(45587, 48042, 47934, 40098),
    Concentration_0.1 = c(32750, 41024, 39483, 34704),
    Concentration_0.01 = c(45407, 53434, 48684, 42951),
    Concentration_0 = c(101895, 132464, 103751, 108483)
)

# Step 2: Reshape the data to long format using tidyr
long_data <- data %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
                 names_to = "Concentration", 
                 values_to = "Value")

# Step 3: Calculate the averages and standard errors for each concentration
average_data <- long_data %>%
    group_by(Concentration) %>%
    summarize(Average = mean(Value), .groups = "drop")

# Calculate the standard error
se_data <- long_data %>%
    group_by(Concentration) %>%
    summarize(SE = sd(Value) / sqrt(n()), .groups = "drop")

# Merge averages and standard errors into a single data frame
average_data <- merge(average_data, se_data, by = "Concentration")

# Step 4: Convert Concentration to a factor for proper ordering
long_data$Concentration <- factor(long_data$Concentration, 
                                   levels = c("Concentration_100", 
                                              "Concentration_10", 
                                              "Concentration_1", 
                                              "Concentration_0.1", 
                                              "Concentration_0.01", 
                                              "Concentration_0"))

# Step 5: Perform the one-way ANOVA
anova_result <- aov(Value ~ Concentration, data = long_data)

# Step 6: Run Tukey's HSD (Post-Hoc Test)
tukey_result <- TukeyHSD(anova_result)

# Step 7: Extract only comparisons with Concentration_0
tukey_comparisons <- tukey_result$Concentration

# Filter to show comparisons with Concentration_0
comparisons_with_control <- tukey_result$`Concentration`[
    grep("Concentration_0", rownames(tukey_result$`Concentration`), 
         ignore.case = TRUE), ]

# Print the filtered comparisons
print(comparisons_with_control)

# Step 8: Define a custom color palette for the columns (from light to dark blue)
blue_colors <- c(
    "Concentration_100" = "#A3C9F1",  # light blue
    "Concentration_10"  = "#6FA9D2",  # medium-light blue
    "Concentration_1"   = "#3989B1",  # medium blue
    "Concentration_0.1" = "#1F6C96",  # darker blue
    "Concentration_0.01" = "#115F82", # dark blue
    "Concentration_0"   = "#0C4E6D"   # darkest blue
)

# Find the maximum value in the data to ensure it's not clipped
max_value <- max(long_data$Value, na.rm = TRUE)  # Get the maximum value from the raw data points

# Set the upper limit for the y-axis to be a bit higher than the maximum value
y_axis_limit <- max_value * 1.1  # Increase by 10% to add some space

# Step 9: Create the plot with significance indicators and custom colors
ggplot() +
    # Add the average columns (bar heights) with custom colors
    geom_col(data = average_data, aes(x = Concentration, 
                                       y = Average, fill = Concentration), 
             width = 0.6, color = "black") +  
    
    # Add individual data points in front of the columns
    geom_jitter(data = long_data, aes(x = Concentration, y = Value), 
                color = "black", size = 3, width = 0.2, 
                height = 0, alpha = 0.8, shape = 21, fill = "gray") +
  
    # Add standard error bars
    geom_errorbar(data = average_data, aes(x = Concentration, 
                                           ymin = Average - SE, ymax = Average + SE), 
                  width = 0.2, color = "black") +
  
    # Customize axis labels and title
    labs(x = "Bortezomib (µM)",  # x-axis title
         y = "Relative Fluorescence Intensity (544/590 nm)") +  # y-axis title
  
    # Adjust x-axis labels to show just the concentration values
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Concentration_100" = "100",
                                "Concentration_10" = "10", 
                                "Concentration_1" = "1",
                                "Concentration_0.1" = "0.1", 
                                "Concentration_0.01" = "0.01", 
                                "Concentration_0" = "0")) +
  
    # Adjust the y-axis to reduce padding (set expand to c(0, 0) to remove space above the columns)
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, y_axis_limit)) +  
  
    # Apply the custom color palette
    scale_fill_manual(values = blue_colors) +
  
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, 
                                     colour = "black"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
          axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5),  # Add axis lines
          panel.background = element_blank(),  # Remove panel background
          panel.grid = element_blank(),  # Remove grid lines
          legend.position = "none",  # Remove the legend
          axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = "black")) +  
  
    # Add significance indicators using ggsignif for only comparisons with Concentration_0
    geom_signif(
        comparisons = list(
            c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_100"),
            c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_10"),
            c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_1"),
            c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_0.1"),
            c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_0.01")
        ),
        map_signif_level = TRUE, textsize = 3, 
        y_position = y_axis_limit * 1.05
    )


Chatgpt can't help me for this one

Hi, Welcome.  This is a lot of code not needed to analyze the question. Could you edit and include the smallest amount of code possible that produces the problem.  If you could use a built in or artificial data set, even better.  If people can copy and paste the code and see the problem, that makes it easier to advise.

You're not passing any data or aesthetic mapping to geom_signif(). Either add it to the ggplot function, or the geom_signif. Also, the y_position is out of range, so you'll need to either extend the range or lower it.

You're not passing any data or aesthetic mapping to geom_signif(). Either add it to the ggplot function, or the geom_signif. Also, the y_position is out of range, so you'll need to either extend the y-scale range or lower the value of y_position.
For example:
  geom_signif(
    data = average_data, 
    aes(x = Concentration, 
        y = Average),
    comparisons = list(
      c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_100"),
      c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_10"),
      c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_1"),
      c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_0.1"),
      c("Concentration_0", "Concentration_0.01")
    ),
    map_signif_level = TRUE, textsize = 3, 
    y_position = y_axis_limit * 0.9
  )

